# Executing CMD command idles

Tags: c#, .net, string, cmd, r.net

I have an R Script that I am executing through the following command in CMD:

```
Rscript.exe C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\r_directory\script.R 10 arg2
```

What I want to do now is to build a windows form with C# with a couple of text boxes that will serve as user input for the arguments in the CMD command.

I've attemted to run the command with the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this is to run program from batch System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\file2.bat");

            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "Rscript.exe C:\\Users\\Stefan\\Documents\r_directory\\script.R 10 arg2";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }
    }
}
```

The cmd windows prompts and all I'm geting is:

```
C:\Users\Stefan\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\bin\Debug>
```

The R script is not executed. Any clues why?

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm just starting to learn C#.

Many thanks.

Comment: Start Rscript.exe instead of cmd.exe.

Comment: You *didn't* execute anything. You just started a `cmd.exe` with some arguments that mean nothing. *Don't* pass `cmd.exe` as the executable, pass `rscript.exe`

Comment: You would need a /c to run the command with your current code - running Rscript direct is a far more sensible manner - if you run the command cmd.exe rscript.exe blah.. it will just make a command window, cmd.exe /c rscript.exe blah, will run the rscript etc.

Comment: It worked with RScript.exe instead. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class called **Process** from its own C#

```
Process proc = new Process
       {
          StartInfo =
          {
               FileName = Rscript.exe,
               Arguments = strCmdText,
               RedirectStandardError = true,
               UseShellExecute = false,
               CreateNoWindow = true
          }
       };
proc.Start();
```

Comment: the OP is using process - and your code would not compile.